# Kotlin fragment error LayoutInflater.from(this)

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, fragment

I'm trying to make an item add button in my project. I'm trying to follow a tutorial about it but the difference is I'm coding on a fragment instead of activity. I try to make it up somehow but now when I add "this" to code it turns red and I can't find a way out. Here's the code what should I do?

```
package com.example.myapplication

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.myapplication.databinding.FragmentBlankBinding
import com.example.myapplication.model.UserData
import com.example.myapplication.view.UserAdapter
import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton


class BlankFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var addsBtn:FloatingActionButton
private lateinit var recv:RecyclerView
private lateinit var userList:ArrayList<UserData>
private lateinit var userAdapter:UserAdapter


override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
): View? {

    userList = ArrayList()

    val bind = FragmentBlankBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

    bind.addingBtn.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this@BlankFragment.requireContext(), addsBtn::class.java )
        startActivity(intent)
    }


    bind.mRecycler.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this@BlankFragment.requireContext(), recv::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }

    userAdapter = UserAdapter(this,userList)
    addsBtn.setOnClickListener { addInfo() }
    return bind.root


}

private fun addInfo() {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this)
    val v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_item,null)
    val addDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    addDialog.setView(v)
    addDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok"){
        dialog,_->
    }
    addDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel"){
        dialog,_->
    }
    addDialog.create()
    addDialog.show()

}
}
```

If there's a way to turn the fragment into activity I could try that as well. But I dont want to change the appearance of my app.

This is the link of the whole project;
https://github.com/alphoetraz/auctionnnn.git

Answer (score 0):

An `Activity` is a `Context`, but a `Fragment` isn't. When you call [`LayoutInflater.from()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater#from(android.content.Context)) the parameter is a *`Context`*, which means you *can* pass `this` when you're in an `Activity` - you're passing a `Context`!

If you're in a `Fragment`, you need to get a context, which you usually do by calling `requireContext()` or `getContext()` (the latter is nullable, so `requireContext()` is better unless you know you're in a situation where you might not have access to it right now)